# zlib raw deflate/inflate output mismatch

Tags: c, zlib

I use this example: http://zlib.net/zpipe.c almost literally, with these few alterations because I want to use raw deflate:

deflateInit() -> `deflateInit2(&strm, 8, Z_DEFLATED, -15,MAX_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);`
inflateInit() -> `inflateInit2(&strm, -15);`

Source and dest are this on deflate:

```
FILE* source = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
FILE* dest = fopen("output", "w+");
```

And on inflate:

```
 FILE* src = fopen("output", "r+");
 FILE* dst = fopen("test2.txt", "w+");
```

I compress a textfile of 601.7kb, and then I decompress it but about 8kb are missing on the inflated file. How can that be?

Answer (score 1):

Using raw with zlib is hinky with streams. I went through this in depth last month. The loop termination conditions get very weird (EOF on the stream vs. complete inflation). zlib (seems to) want the checksum at the end of the stream to force the last block out, which doesn't happen with unwrapped data. If you give inflate the entire block at one time (which is what I need anyway) it works fine but I could never get unwrapped to work reliably with a multi-block loop. It varies by data too. I had some termination tweaks that would terminate correctly with some data but not others.

Comment: Hm, I just tried it without loops, but I'm still getting mismatches. For example, with this jpeg image:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/700060/thumbnail.jpg and this gist https://gist.github.com/dd8c094d137223b3cb0d ...the resulting thumbnail2.jpg has several less kb after inflate. I know it's pretty pointless to compress images, but it should still work. If it doesn't work everywhere, I can't trust it.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't loop the input but I do loop the output, vis-à-vis https://gist.github.com/1441331. Agreed that if it doesn't work reliably, it's useless. When I was debugging, I round-tripped everything. That doesn't prove there's not a case that will foul up, of course, Everything I've been doing is ASCII.

Comment: I just saw that it doesn't even work if I keep everything at default. I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(. Even with the exact pipe.c code, the image isn't having the correct output size and I'm getting an error on inflate: zpipe: invalid or incomplete deflate data

Comment: smparkes, it looks like there was some issue with using zlib in a c++ project. I don't know why, but as soon as I switched to gcc / clang, it worked.

Comment: With the normal streaming? That's great (even if it doesn't match my experience.) You said gcc/clang. Which one? Those two are mutually exclusive. I definitely still have code that seems to miscompile with clang, though it now compiles okay with llvm-gcc (which it didn't use to, prior to Xcode 4.2)

Comment: I just mean, I switched from g++. It works with both gcc and clang

Answer (score 1):

What platform is this on?  You may need to specify binary in the fopen() calls.  E.g. "wb+", "rb+".  The ratio of lost bytes to total of 75 leads me to think that that's an average line length of the text, and that text conversion by fread() may be discarding line feeds.